# ¿Cómo subir archivos de más de 1 MB a un servidor SFTP?

Tags: php, sftp

Estoy tratando de subir archivos a un servidor por medio de SFTP, el problema es que no me permite subir archivos de más de 1 MB. Ya les asigné un valor de 100M a los parámetros `upload_max_filesize` y `post_max_size` en el php.ini, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Código:

```
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$remote = '/home/gnsweb/public_html/archives/'.$image_name;

$conn_id = ssh2_connect('dominio');
$login = ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, 'user', 'password');

if (!$conn_id || !$login) {
    echo "<script>alert('Ha ocurrido un error con la conexión al servidor FTP');
    window.location.href = 'ticket-details.php?idTicket=$idTicket';
    </script>";
} else {
    $upload = ssh2_scp_send($conn_id, $path, $remote, 0644);

    if ($upload) {
        echo "<script>alert('El archivo se ha subido correctamente.');
        window.location.href = 'ticket-details.php?idTicket=$idTicket';
        </script>";
        ssh2_disconnect($conn_id);
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Ha ocurrido un error al subir el archivo.');
        window.location.href = 'ticket-details.php?idTicket=$idTicket';
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Estos son los errores que recibo en en log (reitero que solo aparecen cuando intento subir archivos de más de 1 MB)

> ssh2_scp_send(): Filename cannot be empty in...
>
> ssh2_scp_send(): Unable to read source file in...

Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano :)

Comment: ¿Esto es para una aplicación (por ejemplo donde permitirías a usuarios subir esos archivos), o estás montando algo donde quieres subir `N` cantidad de archivos más o menos grandes? Si es lo segundo, es mucho mejor subirlos desde la consola, conectando tu equipo local y tu servidor remoto. Si es lo primero, eso ya es otra cosa y el tema daría para mucho. Sea como sea, explica mejor el contexto y muéstranos el código con el que estás trabajando y los errores que tengas. Para estos casos conviene revisar el log de errores.

Comment: Hola, deberías especificar cual es tu sftp, porque si es localhost, ahi si toca evaluar porque pasa lo que pasa, pero que tal si es un servidor de pago?, ellos no te van a permitir modificar tu archivo así de simple, deberás solicitar a tu hoster que amplie el tamaño maximo.

Comment: Hola, este sitio web lo tengo alojado en una máquina virtual. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir más detalles

Comment: @A.Cedano sí es una aplicación, ya añadí el código y los errores que me tira

Comment: Vamos a descartar que el problema no es justo lo que dices haber corregido. Agrega esto a tu script PHP y dinos qué muestra: **`printf("MAX permitido: %d MB",ini_get("upload_max_filesize")*1024);`**

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo solucioné, estaba modificando un archivo php.ini equivocado. No me había percatado que hay 2 archivos php.ini en mi servidor

Comment: Me lo supuse, a veces se modifica el `php.ini` que no es, por eso precisamente te propuse que verificaras con [`ini_get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-get.php). Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: También pueden usar el código de la siguiente pagina, implementado por David Barnes: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ssh2-sftp.php